# How can I connect devtools::install_github() to gitcred in R

Tags: r, github-api, devtools

I am moving away from storing my github credentials in `~/.profile` and trying to get them to work with the proper credentials manager (on MacOS Monterey 12.6).

I can connect to a (private) repo using

```
devtools::install_github("myname/myrepo", auth_token = "my_personal_access_token")
```

but I want to be able to do this without entering the PAT every time (I need to regularly switch between repo tags) or recording it into a script. I have tried using

```
gitcreds::gitcreds_set()

-> Your current credentials for 'https://github.com':
protocol: https 
host    : github.com 
username: myname 
password: <-- hidden --> 

-> What would you like to do?
1: Abort update with error, and keep the existing credentials
2: Replace these credentials
3: See the password / token

Selection:
```

and if I look at the password/token, it is correct. However, if I don't include the PAT, it fails:

```
devtools::install_github("myname/myrepo")

Error: Failed to install 'myrepo' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`myname`) and repo name (`myrepo`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

**So, my question is how can I get `install_github()` to get the credentials from `gitcreds` package?**

Here's my `sessionInfo()` if that's useful:

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gitcreds_0.1.2 devtools_2.4.4 usethis_2.1.6 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9          pillar_1.8.1        compiler_4.2.1      later_1.3.0        
 [5] urlchecker_1.0.1    prettyunits_1.1.1   profvis_0.3.7       remotes_2.4.2      
 [9] enstools_0.0.0.9000 tools_4.2.1         digest_0.6.29       pkgbuild_1.3.1     
[13] pkgload_1.3.0       tibble_3.1.8        memoise_2.0.1       lifecycle_1.0.2    
[17] pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_1.0.6         DBI_1.1.3           shiny_1.7.2        
[21] cli_3.4.1           rstudioapi_0.14     curl_4.3.2          fastmap_1.1.0      
[25] stringr_1.4.1       dplyr_1.0.10        generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.4.2        
[29] fs_1.5.2            htmlwidgets_1.5.4   tidyselect_1.1.2    glue_1.6.2         
[33] R6_2.5.1            processx_3.7.0      fansi_1.0.3         sessioninfo_1.2.2  
[37] callr_3.7.2         purrr_0.3.4         magrittr_2.0.3      ps_1.7.1           
[41] promises_1.2.0.1    ellipsis_0.3.2      htmltools_0.5.3     assertthat_0.2.1   
[45] mime_0.12           xtable_1.8-4        httpuv_1.6.6        utf8_1.2.2         
[49] stringi_1.7.8       miniUI_0.1.1.1      cachem_1.0.6        crayon_1.5.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I don't know why this wasn't obvious, but I succeeded in doing:

```
devtools::install_github("myname/myrepo", auth_token=gitcreds::gitcreds_get()$password)
```